# Python Fastest way to check if image is greyscale or color?

Tags: python, rgb, grayscale

I want to check if an image is greyscale or color using Python.  I know we can read in the image and check easily, however, I am wondering if there is a way to check without reading the full image?

I have around 200 million images (200x200), so reading in each image is not feasible in terms of runtime.

Thanks

Comment: The fastest I have found so far: 

meta_data = magic.from_file(fname)
dims = len(re.search('(\d+)x(\d+)', meta_data).groups())
if dims == 2:
   print('greyscale')

Comment: slightly faster is to use PIL and Image open and then check dimensions

Comment: There are very fast ways. Please indicate what formats the images are in - JPEG, TIFF, BMP?

Answer (score 3):

Though I can't say for sure this would be the most efficient, I am certain that it would perform better than most operations.

So consider using ImageStat module.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageStat

def is_grayscale(path="image.jpg")
    im = Image.open(path).convert("RGB")
    stat = ImageStat.Stat(im)
    if sum(stat.sum)/3 == stat.sum[0]: #check the avg with any element value
        return True #if grayscale
    else:
        return False #else its colour
```

**stat.sum** gives us a sum of all pixels in list view = [R, G, B] for example [568283302.0, 565746890.0, 559724236.0]. For grayscale image all elements of list are equal.

Comment: Sorry, I know that the image will only have 1 channel if it's greyscale.  For example, if the image is greyscale, it will be say 200x200.  If it's color, it will be 200x200x3.
Do you know a way that I can decipher the dimensions 'without' loading in the image.  The loading is the part I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Having had another look, I haven't found a better solution. It seems to me that the one you've posted above seems like a good solution. If you are really not looking to load the image then you need to follow the other answer and use the image dimensions. And of course, there is that threshold issue with that as well.

Comment: Thank you man.  Yea, that seems to be the fastest I have found so far.  Out of curiosity, if I move things to the GPU, do you know if the speedup would be on the order of 2-5X or if it would be more like 50X or 100X? I am already using multiple processes with the above solution so I think I've maxed out things on the CPU front

Comment: Also, it's enough to use Image.open and then check dimensions directly for me and make sure its not a 3d matrix. That actually works a little faster than the magic solution I gave above

Comment: That's actually a good idea. From my understanding its mostly suited to parallel processes, such as machine learning, data analysis with also the core emphasis on graphics. But then again there are theories that certain jobs are indeeed faster with gpu. Nothing wrong with trying it.

Comment: @Hvitis can you explain the problem?